# Is a G-invariant metric always Kähler-Einstein?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose there is a Hermitian symmetric space of compact type $X$.  It is realized in the following way: $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^N$ and equipped with the induced Fubini-Study metric $g$.

What's more, the isometry group $G$ of $X$ is a compact subgroup of  the unitary group of $\mathbb{P}^N$.

Let $K$ denote the isotropy group. Assume  $G/K\cong X$, and $G,K$ are the standard pair for Hermitian symmetric space.

> My question:  is $g$ is Kähler-Einstein?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is irreducible, i.e., that $G$ is a simple group?  If so, then, yes, it must be Kähler-Einstein, since there is, up to constant multiples, only one $G$-invariant metric on $X$, and, if it were not Kähler-Einstein, then $g + \epsilon\mathrm{Ric}(g)$ for $\epsilon>0$ and small, would be another $G$-invariant metric that was not a multiple of $g$.

Comment: Yes!  I am assuming it's irreducible!

Comment: Why there is only one G-invariant metric on X?

Comment: Because $K$ acts irreducibly on the tangent space to $G/K$ at the identity coset (this is a consequence of the irreducibility).  Thus, there can be only one $K$-invariant inner product on the tangent space up to constant multiples, and that gives a unique $G$-invariant metric on $G/K$ (up to constant multiples).

Comment: There is a fairly small list of irreducible Hermitian symmetric spaces of compact type.  In algebraic geometry (e.g., positive characteristic), these are the same as the cominuscule projective homogeneous varieties.  In particular, the orthogonal Grassmannian in the Pasquier-Perrin examples is not cominuscule (as it must not be, thanks to the Hwang-Mok rigidity theorem).

Comment: Dear Jason, I don't quite understand your answer.  But I'm very interested in what you are saying.  I asked something about Hwang-amok before as well.  Could you give a little more explanation of your answer?  For example you say HSS of compact type are cominuscule but why orthogonal grassmannian is not?  And what's the relation of it with Hwang-Mok theorem?